# Chrome home page is set to an unwanted website, how do I change it?

Tags: google-chrome

When I use Chrome and go to a page, automatically and without doing anything, it goes to a redirect to the page `repelis.tv` and then to `recpelis.com`.

What can I do? Now I'm using Firefox, but I prefer to use Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Scroll to **Reset Browser Settings** & click
3. Delete **Cookies**
4. Close & restart Chrome

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the reason, why your homepage was changed. Sometimes you could solve it but sometimes your computer is infected by adware, such as ask com and similar. Here is detailed guide how to remove this kind of malware from your computer http://removalbits.com/how-to-uninstall-ask-homepage-from-your-computer-removal-instruction/